# How to read excel files using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, excel

I am trying to display excel sheet data in table format in web page. Currently I am able to read excel data from text area using following code

```
  function generateTable() {
      var data = $('textarea[name=excel_data]').val();
      console.log(data);
      var rows = data.split("\n");

      var table = $('<table />');

      for(var y in rows) {
          var cells = rows[y].split("\t");
          var row = $('<tr />');
          for(var x in cells) {
              row.append('<td>'+cells[x]+'</td>');
          }
          table.append(row);
      }

      // Insert into DOM
      $('#excel_table').html(table);
      }
```

Currently I have paste excel file into text area
How can I modify above code so that I can directly select the excel file and display it without use of text area. I know solution using angular js  or jquery. Can someone tell how to do it using plain javascript

Comment: Take a look at the FileReader object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: I tried following but its not reading console output is blank `function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

    if (f) {
      var data = new FileReader();
         data.onload = function(e) { 
           console.log(data);
         }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation, It was an easier change to request the business department to export their spreadsheets as .csv files rather than develop a solution to parse .xlsx.

Comment: Thanks for comment . I have only excel sheets so if you can please give solution it will be nice